Difficulty using mongoose-paginate-v2 for pagination in TypeScript
I'm encountering issues with pagination using mongoose-paginate-v2 in my TypeScript application. When I attempt to paginate my OfflineMacroAction collection, I'm not receiving any results despite expecting data to be present.
IOfflineMacroAction.ts
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export default interface IOfflineMacroAction extends Document {
    name: string
    order: number
    is_child: boolean
    created_at: Date
    updated_at: Date
    deleted_at: Date

}

offlineMacroAction.ts
import IOfflineMacroAction from "../Interfaces/IOfflineMacroAction";
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
import paginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

const offlineMacroActionSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    
    is_child: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    order: {
        type: Number,
        default: 100
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: null // Optional: Set a default value for the deletedAt field
    }


},
    {
        timestamps: true,
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true }
    });

    offlineMacroActionSchema.virtual('macroaction', {
    ref: 'MacroAction',
    localField: 'macroaction_id', // Of post collection
    foreignField: '_id',    // Of user collection
    justOne: true
})
offlineMacroActionSchema.plugin(paginate);
   
export default mongoose.model<IOfflineMacroAction, mongoose.PaginateModel<IOfflineMacroAction>>('IOfflineMacroAction', offlineMacroActionSchema, 'offlineMacroActions');

and this is how i am calling it.
OfflineMacroAction.paginate({}, options, function (err: any, result: any) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
               // Here you will get paginate array please console and check
               console.log(result);
            }
        });

output
{
  docs: [],
  totalDocs: 0,
  limit: 10,
  totalPages: 1,
  page: 1,
  pagingCounter: 1,
  hasPrevPage: false,
  hasNextPage: false,
  prevPage: null,
  nextPage: null
}

As I have data in in offlinemacroactions collection. Thanks in advance.

export default mongoose.model<IOfflineMacroAction, mongoose.PaginateModel<IOfflineMacroAction>>('IOfflineMacroAction', offlineMacroActionSchema, 'offlinemacroactions');

resolved by fixing the last param which is exact name of collection
